# Pagination in Ajax with select option as main doesn't work in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

This is my select option :

```
<select id="slc_action" class="form-control" style="margin:0;">
    <option value="0"> Select Activity</option>
    <?php foreach($admin_action as $row){
        echo "<option  value='" . $row['action_id'] . "''>" . $row["event"] . "</option>";
     }?>
</select>
```

And this is my jquery :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slc_action").change(function(){
        var action_id = $("#slc_action").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ADMIN/ajax/activity_list',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {action_id: action_id
            },
            success: function(res) {
                if (res)
                {
                    $("#activity_list").html(res);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this is my controller for ajax call :

```
function activity_list(){

    $action_id = $this->input->get("action_id");
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = "/ADMIN/Account/admin_activity/";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Ajax_m->m_count_activity($action_id);
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 5;

    //config for bootstrap pagination class integration
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['num_links'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;
    $data["no"]=$page;
    $data["activity_list"] = $this->Ajax_m->m_get_activity($action_id,$config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view("/ADMIN/".country_code."/Admin_activity_list",$data);
}
```

this for ajax model :

```
function m_get_activity($action_id,$limit,$start){
    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    $this->db->select("admin_name,action_id,querylog,time,");
    $this->db->from("uhd_admin_activity");
    $this->db->where("action_id=",$action_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

function m_count_activity($action_id){
    if($action_id != null) $this->db->where("action_id = '$action_id'" , NULL, FALSE);

    $this->db->from("uhd_admin_activity");

    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

That code in my first view, than if i select the option, it will show the `activity_list` based on the selected.

I put the pagination on that ajax `url`, than if i clicked the pagination, all my `activity_list` will be gone, the selected option will be back to Select Activity.

guys do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Put your controller code  too.

Comment: @RajJagani my controller code is too long.

Comment: Just post your **pagination config settings**

Comment: you want to do ajax pagination after activity list appear or it will refresh the whole page because codeigniter not provide any ajax pagination till now.

Comment: Have you validated that `action_id` is filled by a value?

Comment: sorry for my late comment, yes i have validate the `action_id` in the first view @Glubus

Comment: what should i do? if i clicked the pagination page, the select id will be back to the first selected value @RajJagani

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way.

**In your controller create pagination base_url with your activity_id**

```
$action_id = $this->input->post("action_id"); //please use post method as your are posting data using POST in your ajax call
 $config = array();
 $config["base_url"] = "/ADMIN/Account/admin_activity/".$action_id;
```

**now into your admin_activity function add argument for receiving action_id**

```
function admin_activity($activity_id,$offset) {
    //here $offset will be your page segment no.
   //pass the activity argument along with your view data
   $data['post_activity_id] = $activity_id;
   $this->load->view('view_name',$data);
}
```

**into your view**

```
<select id="slc_action" class="form-control" style="margin:0;">
    <option value="0"> Select Activity</option>
    <?php foreach($admin_action as $row){
        if(isset($post_activity_id) && $post_activity_id == $row['action_id']) {
            echo "<option selected="selected" value='". $row['action_id'] . "''>" . $row["event"] . "</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['action_id'] . "''>" . $row["event"] . "</option>";
        }
     }?>
</select>
```

so, basically you just create your pagination with action_id and after receiving that id in your controller function send it back along with view data and check in your input controller if it set than make that value selected.

Comment: question function admin activity, if for show the select option. than how to get the value of `$activity_id`?

Comment: I am not getting what you are asking ??

Comment: in your second suggest `function admin_activity($activity_id,$offset)` where `$activity_id` come from? because i got an error message Undefined variable: activity_id

Comment: the `$activity_id` is bind with your *pagination url** generated see the line `$config["base_url"] = "/ADMIN/Account/admin_activity/".$activity_id;`